# How to Make Iterating in a For Loop More Efficient?

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to increment by 1 using the i variable. Supposed to be [0x0], [0x1], and [0x2] should be [0xi], however it gives me an error when I try to do that. How do I make this more efficient?

Also, what kind of data type is [0x0]? I've never encountered this before.

Stuff I tried:

1. declaring a variable in another variable using the "%"
2. placing the numbers in an array and then iterating by one
3. tried placing the other variable using the `"<characters> + <variable> + <characters>"`

The Code:

```
for i in range(0, 296, 1):
        time.sleep(5)
        print(" ")
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x03, [0x0])
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x01, [0x0])
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x01)
        res_1 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x03)
        res_2 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        print "Resistance Channel-0 : %.2f K" %res_1
        print "Resistance Channel-1 : %.2f K" %res_2

        print(" ")
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x03, [0x1])
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x01, [0x1])
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x01)
        res_1 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x03)
        res_2 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        print "Resistance Channel-0 : %.2f K" %res_1
        print "Resistance Channel-1 : %.2f K" %res_2

        print(" ")
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x03, [0x2])
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x01, [0x2])
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x01)
        res_1 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x03)
        res_2 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
        print "Resistance Channel-0 : %.2f K" %res_1
        print "Resistance Channel-1 : %.2f K" %res_2
```

Comment: It's just a list containing a single element, which in this case is a number written as hex. You can do `[i]`. Also, making this into a loop won't make it more efficient, but it will make it easier to read. I assume that was your intention.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that it should be like "bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x03, [0x[i]])" ?? If not, could you please clarify? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x2C`, `0x03`, `0x0`, `0x1`  etc are all just `int` literals written in hexadecimal notation. The resulting values are the same as `44`, `3`, `0`, `1`, etc. Your functions are doing any necessary conversion of `int` values to other types.

The following are exactly identical:

```
bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2c, 0x03, [0x1])
bus.write_i2c_block_data(44, 3, [i])  # Assuming i == 1
```

In full,

```
for i in range(0, 296, 1):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(" ")
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x03, [i])
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(0x2C, 0x01, [i])
    data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x01)
    res_1 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
    data = bus.read_byte_data(0x2C, 0x03)
    res_2 = (data / 256.0 ) * 10.0
    print "Resistance Channel-0 : %.2f K" %res_1
    print "Resistance Channel-1 : %.2f K" %res_2
```